# How to include multiple XML namespaces in HTML5

Tags: html, xhtml, namespaces, facebook-opengraph, doctype

I'm trying to include [Facebook's OpenGraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) new [meta tags](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags) but when I add the required namespaces that would have worked in XHTML, HTML5 won't validate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

Where is the proper place to put these namespaces with HTML5?

Answer (score 4):

There are no namespaces in HTML5 AFAIK:

http://mortalpowers.com/news/no-namespaces-in-html5

Answer (score 4):

There is no proper place in HTML5 for the `xmlns:og` or `xmlns:fb` attributes.

(One might argue that there is in HTML5 *plus some other spec that modifies the requirements of HTML5*. But not in HTML5 proper. Validator.nu and the W3C HTML5 validator don't support the kind of "HTML5 *plus some other spec that modifies the requirements of HTML5*" configuration that would make the `xmlns:og` or `xmlns:fb` attributes validate.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [XHTML5](http://blog.whatwg.org/xhtml5-in-a-nutshell) to validate it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en">
<!--...-->
</html>
```